# Error Installing dependencies

Tags: hardhat, error, installation

I cloned the starter kit into decentraTwitter folder, cd into that folder and ran npm install. Now I’m getting this error in the terminal:

```
npm WARN deprecated ganache-core@2.13.2: ganache-core is now ganache; visit https://trfl.io/g7 for details
npm WARN deprecated ganache-core@2.13.2: ganache-core is now ganache; visit https://trfl.io/g7 for details
npm WARN deprecated testrpc@0.0.1: testrpc has been renamed to ganache-cli, please use this package from now on.
npm WARN deprecated source-map-resolve@0.6.0: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-resolve#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated querystring@0.2.0: The querystring API is considered Legacy. new code should use the URLSearchParams API instead.
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated svgo@1.3.2: This SVGO version is no longer supported. Upgrade to v2.x.x.
npm WARN deprecated @ensdomains/ens@0.4.5: Please use @ensdomains/ens-contracts
npm WARN deprecated @ensdomains/resolver@0.2.4: Please use @ensdomains/ens-contracts
```

Any suggestions on how I can fix this issue. I’ve looked on all the websites on google when I searched up this error, and used what they did to fix, but hasn’t worked for me.

Comment: Consider using my [Hardhat template](https://github.com/paulrberg/hardhat-template).